# How to determine which page number links to display

Tags: perl, pagination

I am trying to figure out how determine which page links to display at the bottom of by list of listings. Say I have 90 pages of results. I want to have a link to page 1 and 90 always and then 3-4 pages left and right of the current page if possible.

[] - indicates current page

page 1:
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 90

page 2:
1 [2] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 90

page 20:
1 ... 17 18 19 [20] 21 22 23 ... 90

I am having trouble figuring out the logic. So, give input of: total_number of pages and current page, generate a list of pages to display. I am using perl, but an example in another language would be fine as well.

Comment: Have you tried google.  I think you'll find many examples.  http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Pageset/  Core concept of pagination has been explained many times.  Sure you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should suit you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use constant MARGIN => 3;

say join ', ', page_numbers(2, 90);
say join ', ', page_numbers(30, 90);
say join ', ', page_numbers(88, 90);

sub page_numbers {

  my ($this, $total) = @_;

  my $min = $this <= MARGIN + 1 ? 2 : $this - MARGIN;
  my $max = $this >= $total - (MARGIN + 1) ? $total - 1 : $this + MARGIN;

  return 1, $min..$max, $total;
}
```

**output**

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 90
1, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 90
1, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90
```